# sqlalchemy, connect to a sqlexpress instance on a different port

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm connecting successfully to my sqlexpress instance from sqlalchemy with the connection string:

```
connection_str = 'mssql+pyodbc://mylaptop\sqlexpress/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0&trusted_connection=yes'
```

How would i connect to a sql instance on a non default port, is it possible?

```
connection_str = 'mssql+pyodbc://mylaptop\sqlexpress:1433/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0&trusted_connection=yes'
```

is what i would expect the connection string to be but this returns the error:

```
(pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n (10061) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (10061)
```

I've tried a number of combinations with the port but don't see a legal combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SQLAlchemy connection URI you can specify a SQL Server instance in one of two ways

1. `server_name\instance_name`, **or**
2. `server_name:port`

You should only be using one or the other. If you specify the instance_name then the port number is provided by the SQL Browser service on server_name. If you specify the port then the actual instance_name doesn't matter because the port number is already known.